# Retagging: Comparisons, analogies, and examples, *oh my!*

Tags: discussion, retagging

Tag proposal number 1:

Change [teaching-analogy](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-analogy) to [examples](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples), in line with [matheducators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples)

Upvote if you agree, downvote if you disagree, or answer if there are additional considerations.

Comment: If/when done, we can also create the synonym from teaching-analogy to examples as well.

Comment: I don't agree. I see them as different things. [tag:examples] might refer to examples for coding something as a means of teaching. [tag:teaching-analogy] refers to the way to describe a paradigm, concept, idea etc. to students in a simple way.